# Implement mysql table structure to Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, relationship

Hopefully this is okay to ask here. Not a coding question, but rather a "where do I start" question. For hours I tried figuring out if it's worth to do this in Wordpress or not.

I have a music library, and post reviews of each song. I got my MySQL tables working; easy to pick artist/album for each song I want to publish. However, if I want to do this in Wordpress, is it a lot of hassle to get working nicely? I've been reading about custom post types but I'm not sure how to get all the relationship databases to work together and all to the actual post.

I want to be able to pick artist names and album names. What is preferred, use Wordpress or set up something myself? It's a lot of songs, albums and artists.

Comment: Wordpress is based on php you could add functionality to your site maybe a sidebar that would use a prepared PDO statement to pass your data to a drop down list that then can be used to select data and send it to a view.

Comment: Using Wordpress leads to two things - you either embrace super, mega crappy stupid way of doing things and think that's the way to go or you pull all your hair out with its stupid ways of doing things. If you want to keep your sanity, or avoid getting polluted by code that someone created while learning PHP then **avoid Wordpress**. **TL;DR:** set something up yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies! I think that settles it, I'll avoid Wordpress for this as you suggest N.B.